# Two-Body Problem on a Frictionless Table with a Hanging Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

> Here's the situation. There are two boxes connected by a string. Box A is on a frictionless table. A string attached to Box A runs over a frictionless pulley and is attached to the hanging Box B. Calculate the acceleration from the POV of both Box A and Box B.

When I attempt this problem the accelerations don't agree and I can't figure out why.

$\\$

**BOX A**

The forces acting on Box A are the force of gravity $F_{gA}$, the normal force $F_{NA}$, and the tension in the string $F_T$. Clearly, $F_{gA}$ and $F_{NA}$ cancel each other out. Therefore, the net force on Box A is $F_T$. Then,

$F_{netA}=F_T \ $ but $F_{netA}= m_A a\ $ and $F_T=m_Bg \ $ so

$m_A a=m_Bg$

$a=\frac{m_B}{m_A}g\ \ $ which is the acceleration of the entire system from the POV of Box A.

$\\$

**BOX B**

The forces acting on Box B are the force of gravity $F_{gB}$ and the tension in the string $F_T$ in the opposite direction. Therefore, the net force on Box B is

$F_{netB}=F_{gB} - F_T \ $ but $F_{netB}=m_B a $, $F_{gB}=m_Bg $, and $F_T=m_Aa\ $ so

$m_B a=m_Bg - m_Aa$

$a=\frac{m_B}{m_A+m_B}g\ \ $ which is the acceleration of the entire system from the POV of Box B.

$\\$

**The Problem**

Clearly, the acceleration from Box A and the acceleration from Box B don't agree. My only assumption that the tension in the string is the same in both directions $F_T=m_Aa=m_Bg $. Where is my mistake? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F_T=m_Bg$ as you claim, then box B would never accelerate.

Comment: That is an excellent point. 

So what would the tension in the string be from the perspective of Box A? I reasoned that it couldn't be $F_T=m_Ba$ because that would mean that $F_T=m_Ba=m_Aa$ which would mean either the tension in the string isn't the same or that the two boxes have different accelerations.

Comment: @Tim Use Newton's second law. $F_T=m_Aa=m_Bg-m_Ba$

Comment: Yes thank you! It's very obvious now in retrospect.